# Elasticsearch Aliasing a field during search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Using Elasticsearch v 5.X.

Jumped into a rather strange requirement and need ideas on approach here.
I've got an index with fields F1, F2, F3 (Just for illustration purposes).
I want to remove the field F2 and F3 from the mapping as they represent the same value as F1. I'm doing this to avoid duplicates and save some space.

But the issue I have is on the existing APPS that are searching this index. These APPs are ones that we don't manage. They still continue to use F2 and F3 as part of their search requests.

Is there any approach where I could transparently do this perhaps like field aliasing during search (ie if someone searches for F2 and F3, I'd instead search on F1).

The challenge here is that I'd want to do this in a transparent way without affecting my search APPs(clients). Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this post is rather late and not applicable to 5x. However, if someone is looking for a solution, creating field aliases was introduced in 6.4 (and requires indexes created in 6.0 or later).

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/alias.html